# WPF - Installing the certificate automatically for client

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, digital-certificate

We have a program in WPF. In order for clients to run this program, they first need to manually install our certificate on their PCs.

Is there a way to make the program automatically prompt the user to install the certificate or approve installation of certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
Create a bat file and run this, either as a process inside your main application like a first run sort of deal or have it execute as part of your installer.